# Отладчик Visual Studio 2012 интерпретирует код иначе чем система Windows 7

Tags: отладка, visual-studio-2012

Я поставил все проекты в режим Debug , нажимаю Start Debugging, компилирует, запускается без ошибок. Я смотрю на консоль worldserver, при наведении мыши на консоли показывает директорию откуда она запущена. Я в эту папку переместил файлы конфигурации worldserver.conf и authserver.conf, а также все dll файлы, нужные для работы. Запускаю отладчик еще раз. Он снова все запускает, никаких ошибок (кстати я пробовал сначала с pdb файлами на dll и lib , но потом отключил, так как они и так работают нормально). В итоге у меня вылет приложения. Я игрался с брек - поинтами и установил что вылет происходит в начале выполнения main.cpp
Код: (хотя я понимаю что это ничего не дает. Но для визуализации происходящего

```
{
    extern int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        std::string configFile = _TRINITY_CORE_CONFIG;
        std::string configService;

        auto vm = GetConsoleArguments(argc, argv, configFile, configService);
        // exit if help is enabled
        if (vm.count("help"))
            return 0;
    ...................
    ..................
    ................
    }
}
```

vm.count("help") возвращает 2, что приводит к остановке приложения с надписью "Не удается загрузить настройки с файла worldserver.conf". К чему бы это все? Если я тут же открываю директорию откуда был вызван worldserver.exe, запускаю и .... он спокойно работает вплоть до сигнала полной готовности.
Помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Почему так происходит? Как я могу работать с отладчиком, если код в нем выполняется не так как в живую? Как на него можно полагаться вообще? Или я просто что-либо делаю не правильно?

Я попытался проследить шаг за шагом код, но как вы понимаете, он выполняет коды стандартных библиотек, я не думаю что там могут быть ошибки, и к тому же там довольно низкий уровень что ничего не понятно. Да и чтоб протыкать этот весь код мне понадобилось 4 часа и толку ноль вообще.(((
Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Прошу удалить этот глупый вопрос. Он действительно никому не приносит пользы. Я его задал из-за отчаянья решить проблему. Спасибо Александру что помог. Было предложено открепить вопрос от моего аккаунта - но по ссылке меня просто кидает на англоязычный форум.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, в свойствах проекта - Debugging - Working dir указан отличный от того, где находятся исполняемые файлы, в таком случае он не может найти файл настроек worldserver.conf.
И не понятно, для чего указан *extern*?

Comment: Я посмотрел в настройках worldserver ? пишет $(ProjectDir), ну я вообще нашел две папки с worldserver.exe. 
И кинул файлы в обе. К тому же я писал что навел мышкой на окошко  worldserver.exe и там был указан путь откуда его вызвали. Туда я все и положил с самого начала

Comment: как вариант, попробовать указать абсолютный путь к файлу worldserver.conf

Comment: Круто да.... Я благодарю. Он искал файлы в другой папке, хотя я думал что они должны лежать непосредственно с exe-шником.